# How to have responsive widths for labels and inputs using css

Tags: html, css

I have done the following with my forms:

[image]

Noe everything is fine when I have it on a large screen. But when I test it in my ripple emulator in the browser I get this, the screen size was a 240x320:

[image]

Here is my CSS:

```
.inputbox{
            width: 80%;
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
            border-top-right-radius: 2em;
            box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px #ececec;
            display: inline;
            padding: 8px;
            font-size: 100%;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 1%;
        }

        .labelbox{
            border-bottom-left-radius:2em;
            border-top-left-radius: 2em;
            padding: 8px;
            display: block;
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            background: #e9f939; /* Old browsers */
            padding-right: 5px;
            color:black;
            float:left;
            width:17.5%;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<label class="labelbox" for="textareacontactus">Enter Title*</label>
<input type="text" class="inputbox" data-role="none" ng-model="searchtitle" name="searchtitle" id="searchtitle" required>

    <label class="labelbox" for="searchauthor">Enter Author</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputbox" data-role="none" name="searchauthor" id="searchauthor">

    <label class="labelbox" for="searchpublisher">Enter Publisher</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputbox" data-role="none" name="searchpublisher" id="searchpublisher">

    <label class="labelbox" for="searchedition">Enter Edition</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputbox" data-role="none" name="searchedition" id="searchedition" ng-model="searchedition" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/">
```

Now in the CSS I used width but using the %. So I can't see why its doing this? I would assume by using % it will always take up say 20% relative to the screen size because if this was the case then why does it do this on the emulator? What is the best practice to ahieve this responsive design?

Comment: Have you heard of media queries?

Comment: Is this the only way to do it? Using media queries?

Comment: So in the jQUery Mobile framework they've written tons of media queries for different screen sizes?

Comment: @Roberto Really? while you didn't add JavaScript tag on your question?

Comment: I don't have much idea about that, I just answered you keeping standards in mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) such as `@media (max-width: 767px)`


Another thing you could try is using an HTML table like in this JSFiddle I made from your existing code: http://jsfiddle.net/ALYxt/